# Hosting Prestashop on iPage: Front office works, but can't log into back office, there is no error

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

> Seems like people misunderstood my intention, I didn't mention iPage
>   before, but since I found my solution and it is somehow related to the
>   hosting provider I changed the title. Should anyone get into the same
>   problem as I did they would be searching this on the internet and find
>   this post which is exactly what I did before

I just migrated my prestashop from local host to a live server (iPage). Which means to a different domain. I've tried to follow the instruction from here [Moving Prestashop Documentation](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/System+Administrator+Guide#SystemAdministratorGuide-MovingPrestaShop). First I got problem with the backoffice ui because I used to put the installation in a folder. So I need to update the folder to '/' from my local, and I also update the domain to my own domain. After that I uploaded all my files and database to the server. And the front office works well. The backoffice login page also shows up. But when I try to login it does this:

[image: Login]
[image]

Then it just freeze, it doesn't show any error report. Nothing.
There is no problem in the console, and the http requests seem fine too.

I've also turned on the debugging mode from the `defines.inc.php`

```
define('_PS_MODE_DEV_', true);
```

I've increased the `max_memory` from `php.ini` to 256M

This is so frustrating, I don't know what to do anymore.

PHP Version 5.3, MySQL Version 5.5.44, and OS Ubuntu 12

EDIT:

Wait a minute, the http request return the **entire login page** for some reason. But there is no error message in the source. There is just this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var img_dir = '/img/';
    var more_errors = 'There are some errors.';
    var one_error = 'There is an error.';
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use iPage hosting and I checked the error log from the menu CGI and Scripted Language Support > Check Error Logs. It says:

> PHP Warning:  Unknown: POST Content-Length of 150 bytes exceeds the
>   limit of 120 bytes in Unknown on line 0

Then I found out that my `post_max_size` parameter in php.ini is messed up. It's finally fixed now. Thanks everyone...